# How to traverse all the element of dropdown in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

I have a drop down on my web page and I have to traverse this drop down and select the specific one.But its not so simple, In this the traversing should be show by the hover and at last the specific element or item should be selected.(The mouse hover action should start from the first element till the required element and then select the element).

Comment: show some code and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    is it a normal select box or a custom one?

Comment: Have you done something on this? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [Select](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html), there are a couple of different ways of selecting elements from the dropdown, below is one example.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(<WebElement>);
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("text");
```

Comment: The code which you have given is working fine. But i don't want in this way. I want that first Web Driver click on the Drop down button and then it moves mouse to First item of the list and then second and so on till web Driver finds the element in drop box and the after it selects the item from the list. I want to see how the mouse starts from first step and then second , third and then selects the fourth item. Each step should be seen.

Comment: without seeing what you have already tried i cant give you anymore help. Read the api i linked above, the thing you are interested in is selectByIndex().